Creating an exam template
I'm trying to create an exam template and I was wondering how I might customize my code so that every time I do the following:
\begin{question}
   \begin{parts}
     \part[]
       \begin{subparts}
       \subpart[1]

       \end{subparts}
     \end{parts}
\end{question}

It can generate three cells as attached in the image: 
I'm not looking for an entirely new code! I'm just hoping for some pointers so I know which direction to go in.

You'd better supplement the code such that the correspondence with the elements of the image is more clear.
